# How to stop iterating over a list once a certain value is reached

Tags: python, list, iteration

For this problem, a list of integers is given. I need to find the average  of the list. The only problem is, once you reach a negative number, you aren't supposed to factor in any of the numbers after that into the calculations. This is what I have so far:

```
def average_rainfall(listInts):
    newList = []
    count = 0
    for num in listInts:
        if num < 0:
            newList.append(listInts[:num])
            count += (1*len(newList))
        else:
            newList.append(listInts)
            count += (1*len(newList))

    summ = sum(newList)
    avg = summ/count

    return avg
```

The list and function call are below:

```
a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1, 6, 7]
print(average_rainfall(a_list))
```

I've been working on this for a while and am stuck. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `itertools.takewhile` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile)):

```
from itertools import takewhile

a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1, 6, 7]

def average_rainfall(listInts):
    l = [*takewhile(lambda k: k >=0, listInts)]
    return sum(l) / len(l)

print(average_rainfall(a_list))
```

Prints:

```
3.0
```

Comment: So Python has a "pythonic" way to break a loop too... LOL. I love it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `break` inside inside the `if` block to exit the loop early.

Something like

```
def average_rainfall(listInts):
    newList = []
    count = 0
    for num in listInts:
        if num < 0:
            newList.append(num)
            count += 1
            break
        else:
            newList.append(num)
            count += 1

    summ = sum(newList)
    avg = summ/count

    return avg
```

Edit: There is a bug in your `append` statements. You need to append the `num` you are currently iterating on, not the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic use case for `continue` or `break`. To determine which one that you want you have to decide whether or not you want to skip over negative numbers or stop execution entirely.

`continue` skips one iteration of the loop while `break` stops execution of the loop entirely.